# Is it possible to download iOS 8 beta without Developer Account?

Tags: developer-program, ios

My device is iPhone 5 (American version). Is it possible to get iOS 8 beta without buying access to Developer Account?

Comment: Please note that the [help] specifically prohibits pirated software, so keep that in mind if anyone wants to post links to dubious sources of official software as an answer here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.

You need to be a registered developer agreeing to the license agreements AND your device needs to be registered as a development device.

As always, there are ways around this, but that is illegal. Torrent sites sometimes offer the software and in the comments developers offer to register your device as a development device. But these developers are at risk to lose their own development access.

Furthermore the first betas tend to be buggy. Unless you have an obsessive need for the latest stuff or are a developer you don't actually want it on your phone.

Comment: he didn't ask if he should... he merely asked if he could, and the answer is yes

Answer (score -5):

yes register your udid and download it or wait a couple days or weeks perhaps and wait for the un-registered version to come out

Comment: This could be made better with more explicit instructions on where and how you "register your udid". Also, consider including how you *get* your UDID from your phone.